# Prove that for every $x$ in a group $G$ there is a $y$ such that $y^n=x$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $n$ be a natural number, relatively prime to $|G|$. Prove that for every $x$ in a group $G$ there is a $y$ such that $y^n=x$. 
I really need assistance when it comes to formality, since the main idea I sort of get...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $|G|=m$. Consider the function (as sets, not a group morphism) $f:G\to G$ given by $f(x) = x^n$. Since $G$ is finite, if $f$ is injective then it will be surjective. But if $g^n = h^n$, since $m,n$ are coprime, there are $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $am+bn=1$. Then since $g^m = h^m = 1$ (as $m=|G|$), we will have $g^{am} = h^{am}$ and then $g^{am+bn} = h^{am+bn}$, which is $g=h$. So $f$ is injective.

Thus, as $f$ is surjective, there is an $x\in G$ such that $f(x)=y$. That is $x^n =y$.

Answer (score 7):

**Outline:** Let $m$ be the order of the group. Since $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, there exist integers $s$ and $t$ such that $sm+tn=1$. Then 
$$x=x^1=x^{sm+tn}=(x^t)^n (x^m)^s=(x^t)^n.$$